# unable to scrape the current stock price from yahoo finance website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape the Current Stock Value of any company using `scrapy` whenever I run the `spider` from the below [Yahoo Finance](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ZUO/key-statistics?p=ZUO) :

But i am unable to extract it using scrapy shell as shown in screenshots.

**Screenshot of yahoo finance with red rectangles(details need to be scraped)** :

[image]

---

### **scrapy shell screenshot :**

[image]

---

### **How can I extract this data ?**

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find an element that is supposed to be in a page, I suggest you use `view(response)`. It shows you how the scrapy see the page. 
In this case, if you use it by yourself, you can see that in fetched HTML, there is no price element. I set a normal user agent in the request and it worked properly

```
request=scrapy.Request('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ZUO/key-statistics?p=ZUO', headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
fetch(request)
response.xpath('//*[@id="quote-header-info"]/div[3]/div/div/span[1]').extract()
```

Result:

```
[u'<span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">27.40</span>']
```